# How to create a validation code for account setup that is provided by the company to an approved user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registration, account

I am trying to create a website that when a person registers with the site they have to have an access pin (or code) to complete creating the account. The person creating the account in a sense would be submitting an application to receive permission to view the data. I understand how to block anonymous users, but want a code generated that is sent to an employee which they would review the application to view the data and would determine whether to send the approval code. To add, I'm hoping to have the key as a rotating key which has to be provided by our company for people to create an account with us.

What I'm hoping to have once the account has been approved that the page is as follows:

Email Address

Password

Account Passcode (The part I'm wondering on how to tackle)

The email address and password I know they are built-in functions for these first two; however, looking at having a passcode to activate the account which has to be provided by the company after they have verified that the user falls within our guidelines for acceptable usage.

---

Edit: The data itself isn't confidential and just best practices and how to guides to using our medical products we support. The main focus is to keep patients from finding the information on the internet and performing self-treatment. No vital information, secrets, or confidential information is used.

To add, it would almost be like having an owner's manual for a vehicle that you only want a certified mechanic to use because you're afraid of the average joe misunderstanding the information, using something incorrectly, or ends up hurting themselves from improper use of the tools.

Comment: You tagged your question ASP.NET; why would you not use the account support [already built-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx)?

Comment: You could create the account in a disabled state, then generate a key and send the key by email, for example. Then an user can activate that account using the key provided.

Comment: Encrypt user name with one way encryption and salt to get passcode, then when user passes user name and passcode in the url you will be able to validate. MS Framework provides encryption classes.

Comment: If you want to determine the keys in advance, then you could create a table which has some user specific identifier (like email) and that user's pin, then check that before you complete the account creation process.

Comment: It's not simple straight forward because it's a fairly odd requirement. What are you hoping to accomplish with the PIN?

Comment: I'm hoping to have an automated way for a rotating key that can only be provided by the company. We are medical research company where our information is not intended for public domain and only for licensed healthcare providers. I hope that adds some clarity on why I want to do it the way I'm asking.

Comment: Ohh dear <deity>, please don't use my example code for that...  Now I really am considering deleting it.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to allow anyone to register in your service, but to restrict privileges only to user accounts that your company trusts. This is how everyone else does it.

Comment: Using a Guid rather than a rotating pin would be a major improvement.

Comment: I personally would like it if the system generated the code similar to your example Bradley Uffner; however, has to be provided by phone or direct email from an employee. Even though it's not a perfect fit it does suggest some steps that I can take.

I do like Jeroen idea also of having an account setup for that is deactivated and require a pin to enable it.

Comment: @DourHighArch -- What you suggest is preventing anonymous people from accessing web pages. What I'm looking for is how to have a validation code that has to be provided and rotates for a user to create an account.

Comment: @DourHighArch I selected ASP.NET since I'm working with building a dynamic website that uses the .NET framework. If there is a better tag to use, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the core of your problem is that you do not separate authentication from authorization.

I work in the health care industry as well. The way we secure data is the following:

1. Anyone can register on our application. Once they are registered however, they only have access to features and data that require no security.
2. Another application is only accessible by our staff. This application allows our staff to grant and revoke privileges for users.
3. We have a procedure for establishing which user account. This is authentication, and is up to you to figure out. Identity verification is a large and complex problem that is way outside the scope of StackOverflow.
4. Once we are confident that a user account really does belong to who they say they are, we grant privileges to the account.
5. From this point on, the user can access medical data and secure features.

Now if you want to persist in your PIN solution, you must keep the following in mind:

First, the security of your PIN is directly related to its length. The PIN is a so-called shared secret in IT security parlance. Currently, the acceptable length of shared secrets is 256 bits according to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). I would actually recommend that you read a lot of OWASP as it will guide you in how to secure your application.

If after reading all this you still persist on using a PIN, I would recommend finding an entropy source to generate a GUID that your customers will trust.

Comment: I appreciate this general information. Which shed some light on the topic. I know for this circumstance that basic security is only needed; additionally, if in the future I need to create something that does have confidential information that this will be useful.

Comment: @JeremyHinz I'm afraid I must insist. A PIN is not basic security, it is no security. Healthcare software in the US is overseen by [HIPAA](http://searchhealthit.techtarget.com/definition/HIPAA) . A 5 digit PIN for authentication is an egregious security vulnerability that will land your application on the front page of multiple IT-related news sites.

Comment: So what you are saying even though it's not confidential or secret data that I need to follow HIPAA compliance since it falls under the realm of medicine which is still governed by HIPAA?

Comment: @JeremyHinz The list of medical data that is not confidential is surprisingly small. HIPAA is the authority on what constitutes confidential data. The simplest example we use at work is that a single message containing a patient id and a doctor id constitutes PHI. If, after reading the HIPAA guidelines, you still believe this isn't confidential, then you are home free, and security is not required.

Comment: @JeremyHinz I read your comment on the other answer. That does look like non-confidential data. In that case, you are not bound by HIPAA.

Answer (score 0):

---

**EDIT: Ohh dear (god, gods, rocks, whatever you believe in), please do not use this method to secure confidential medical data.**

---

The easiest way to create the rotating PIN like you describe would be to figure out the interval that you want it to rotate on (hours, days, weeks, etc), reduce the current date and time to that interval, then hash it down to a shorter, easier to enter number that you can give to users as needed. Whether or not this whole plan is a good idea or not, I'll leave up to you, but it isn't something I would recommend.

As a very simple example, this is a (**very poor**) method of generating a PIN for a particular date.  Please do not use this method in your real program, it is for demonstration purposes only.  I'm not responsible if you *do* use it, and get hacked.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(GetPinForDate(new DateTime(2017, 7, 26)));
    Console.WriteLine(GetPinForDate(new DateTime(2017, 7, 27)));
    Console.WriteLine(GetPinForDate(new DateTime(2017, 7, 28)));
    Console.WriteLine(GetPinForDate(new DateTime(2017, 7, 29)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string GetPinForDate(DateTime targetDate)
{
    var days = Math.Floor((targetDate - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalDays);
    return (days.GetHashCode() << 8).ToString().Substring(6);
}
```

It produces the following output:

> 33760
>   68224
>   02688
>   37152

In your real program, you would collect the PIN from the user during registration and compare it to the pin generated by this function for the current date.  If they match, allow the user to continue, if not, yell at them.  You could have a small program that just displays the PIN for the current date using the same method running at your office, that you give out when someone calls and wants to create an account.

---

Just to explain, there are 2 main reasons I don't recommend this pattern.

- The first is that it is just an odd authentication mechanism, it seems inconvenient for you, and is easily bypassed if someone figures out how to generate the PIN pattern.
- In this particular example, the hashing is very weak, and untested. I came up with it in 30 seconds, and only tested it against 5 dates.  There may be (and most likely are) cryptographic weaknesses in it that make guessing the PIN for a particular date fairly trivial.

I better method would be to use the existing authentication mechanisms in MVC. Add an `Approved` flag to your user accounts that is set to `false` by default.  Let users create an account, and call you to request approval and activation, which is done on your end by modifying the flag through a web interface.

Comment: If it's such a poor method, it's not a good idea to suggest it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it.  In fact, my answer specifically says that I do not recommend this authentication mechanism. It does answer the user's question however.

Comment: I've added some notes on the specific reasons *why* I don't recommend this pattern.

Comment: Hi,
The data itself is not confidential. It is general information of care on how doctors should help patients using our care of medical products for practice and want some form of security to keep patients from self-treating themselves.

Comment: @JeremyHinz even if the data is not confidential why would you not just use a already built authentication framework and use the username and password authentication?

Comment: @BrianOgden I'm still a newbie at programming. My understanding is that anyone can sign up using that technique and trying to limit who can sign up for the information. If there is a built-in function with documentation that you know about that will help me out, please link it. I'm not looking at doing two-factor authentication or other common ones I find in the Visual Studio 2015 account functions.

Comment: You can use ASP.NET Identity for all your needs, no point in hand rolling your own solution and no reason to use a pin, make the user provide an email and password to see the information

Comment: @BrianOgden that would be two-factor authentication which is not the goal here. Anyone could sign-up then through those methods. I'm looking at tweaking the registration so they have to type in a  pin or code to get there account approved to view the material.

A similar comparison is when you log on to Facebook from a new device. You need a code sent to you to authorize that device. In this case, it would be authorizing an account. The code would be sent by an employee.

Comment: @JeremyHinz no ASP.NET Identity is not two-factor authentication, ASP.NET Identity, is just authentication, out of the box it includes username/password account creation and sign in, that is not two factor authentication, ASP.NET Identity will also work with multi-factor providers such as Facebook and Google.

Comment: @BrianOgden is there an easy way to tweak the built-in function to add another text box that requires a passcode / pin to allow the account to be created?

Comment: @BrianOgden yes you can add additional columns to the database table for ASP.NET Identity Users, you will still need your password generator to create pins and than ASP.NET Identity users can provide the pin number you issue when they create their account and or login

Comment: Thanks for the clarity Brian. That answers more than just use the built-in features. The feature doesn't exist and the example of the code generator is why I marked it as an answer because that is the part I'm trying to figure out a solution. It may not be the "Best" solution, but sheds some light on a path.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I unmarked your answer as the correct answer since even you are saying it's not good practice or wise to even use something remotely to that.